# Не_ревниво смотреть, чтобы не было больно...

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Возможно ли "не_ревниво смотреть"? Если "не_ревниво" - это наречие, то как оно пишется (не могу найти синоним без "не")?

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, синонимами могут быть слова "равнодушно, спокойно, безучастно"

Answer (score 0):

Если нет явного отрицания, противопоставления и так называемых слов-магнитов, то пишется слитно.

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли "не_ревниво смотреть"?

Вполне. В этом случае более уместно как раз слитное написание.
Полного синонима я Вам, боюсь, не назову, ибо за словом "ревниво", "ревность" стоит весьма неоднозначное понятие. От контекста зависит. Если "на что-то" (успех, богатсво) - то независтливо, если - на жену, то тут можно с десяток вариантов предложить (спокойно, безучастно), но суть такими частичными синонимами передать трудно.